# Drag and Drop into a Table SWT

Tags: java, swt

I'm just starting with swt and I want to be able to have a table where I can drag a file into the table and display the file location in text within the table. I've look a few examples but when I try it myself I get an error.

Here is the offending code:

```
    final Table dropTable = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(dropTable, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("item " + i);
    }

    int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_DEFAULT;
    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(dropTable, operations);
```

The error I'm getting from eclipse is "the constructor DropTable(Table, int) is undefined".
After looking at the JavaDocs, I know that DropTable needs a Controller class and Table does not inherit that class as far as I am aware.

I got the code from here: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html#_Drop_Target

any information on how to fix/do this would be appreciated.

EDIT: SOLVED
The error was caused by using the java.awt import for droptarget instead of the swt import.

Comment: What you have should be OK, make sure you are importing `org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget` and **not** `java.awt.dnd`

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I was using the awt import and not realizing it, thank you for pointing that out for me. Changing the import got it to work.